# my const variable ul is returning undefined array instead of returning an array of objects, how can I get the code to return an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, return

I found a way to get my list items into an array which can be mapped into its different ul component using this piece of code

```
const ul = Object.entries(props.allshop).map(([item, list, index]) => {
  [...Array(Object.keys(list))].map((newItem, index) => {
    return (
      <BuildControl key={index} item={newItem} title={item}></BuildControl>
    );
  });
});
```

However, I still have an issue because ul is returning undefined as the values of the array like this

```
{console.log(ul)} = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

I tried running console.log on my BuildControl component and it returned the objects I was expecting like this :

```
console.log(
  <BuildControl key={index} item={newItem} title={item}></BuildControl>
);
```

reveals the arrays mapped correctly

[image]

Now my challenge is how to get the ul to return this value of the buildControl insteadof undefined

Comment: Your `.map` callback isn’t `return`ing anything…

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the result of the outer map function. You could have an explicit return like below

```
const ul = Object.entries(props.allshop).map(([item, list, index]) => {
  return [...Array(Object.keys(list))].map((newItem, index) => {
    return (
      <BuildControl key={index} item={newItem} title={item}></BuildControl>
    );
  });
});
```

or an implicit return like

```
const ul = Object.entries(props.allshop).map(([item, list, index]) => 
       [...Array(Object.keys(list))].map((newItem, index) => {
        return (
          <BuildControl key={index} item={newItem} title={item}></BuildControl>
        );
      });
    );
```